# React + Webpack5 app experiencing a 'buffer not defined' error

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I created a react app via `npx create-react-app my-app` and got several compile errors about module support.

I know webpack5 does not support some modules automatically, so I added them manually into the `resolve.fallback` in `webpack.config.js`.

While I don't get any more compile errors, I do get another error:

> Buffer is not defined

on the browser.

I want to know how to fix it. InAngular, we can edit `polyfills.ts` like this:

`global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;`

But it is not working in React.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar and I solved it by adding the following to your index.js you will fix the buffer issue:

```
import * as buffer from 'buffer';
window.Buffer = buffer.Buffer;
```

This link references was where I found the solution.

https://github.com/isaacs/core-util-is/issues/27#issuecomment-878969583